# Active Directory Trusted Sites

Tags: active-directory

I have two business units that I need to setup an AD trust(win 2008) between the two different domains, however one of the sites has a DR solution in place (We replicate the DC's etc to an offsite location).
So in the event of DR, it means that site will have to fail over, which means the DR site has no access to the other domain, which is fine, in a DR situation we are ok with this.

But can anyone think (or first hand experience) know of any major issues this setup would have?

Comment: Why can't the DR Situation connect to the other Domain? Can't you connect those Networks?

Comment: I can't think of any issue other than the Trust not being available during a DR situation. Since you've said that you're OK with that then I see no other potential problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 2 different forests or 2 domains in a forest.

If they are between the two forests then the trust will be held by the FSMO roles, which I am assuming you would move if you went into a DR situation the Trust would still be there.

If there is no physical connectivity between the DR site and the site that has the other domain / forest, this won't stop basic functionality, but you will get errors in the event log and you would of course have issues with synchronization.

One way around this is to have a DC for Domain B in the physical DR site of Domain A, and visa versa. These DC themselves would have issues as they lost connectivity to the rest of their domain, but other services could be used